# Eclipse freeze on autocompletion

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ide

The problem has appeared with Eclipse-Indigo 4.3.
I was working with a javascript/threejs file: trying to access a property of an object (obj.something) Eclipse freezes.

So I try to remove Eclipse and install the new version Eclipse4.4 Luna. The same.

I temporarily fixed the problem disabling the auto completion:

```
Window->Preferences->Javascript->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced
  uncheck:
  - "Other Javascript Proposal" 
  - "Template Proposal"
```

Is there anyone knows more about this bug?